# Why is $f(x)=1$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ not integrable, but $f(x)=1$ for $x=1/n$ is?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Consider two functions.

First function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

Second function: Let $E=\left\{1/n, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$, then

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in E\\ 0 & x\notin E\end{cases}$$

Are these functions integrable on $[0,1]$?

The answers says that the first is NOT integrable, but the second is. I don't understand why this is true. they seem to be the same function in my mind.

Comment: There are very few numbers of the form ${1\over n}$, most of them in the immediate vicinity of $0$. On the other hand, the rational as well as the irrational rational numbers in $[0,1]$ are dense in in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Why do you think they are the "same function"? Not every rational number can be written $1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Are you speaking of Lebesgue or Riemann integration ?

Answer (score 1):

The first function is discontinuous on a set that does not have measure zero $[0,1]\cap (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})$. You can see this by convincing yourself there is no suitable partition such that the lower and upper Darboux sums are the same. The upper will always be $1$ for any partition, the lower will always be zero.

The second function is discontinuous on what is called a set of measure zero. You can define a partition with the upper and lower sums both being zero with a little work. Having the same value for upper and lower Darboux sums for a suitable fine partition is what it means to be Riemann integrable.

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing because of the word "since" and your parenthetical about the irrationals being dense. Discontinuous on a dense set does not imply discontinuous everywhere. For example, there is a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) that is discontinuous only on the rationals, which are dense. Besides, we don't need to know the first function is discontinuous everywhere to conclude it isn't integrable. It is enough to note it's discontinuous on the irrationals, for then the set of discontinuities does not have measure zero.

Comment: I added a dense set after and also wasn't sure if op was familiar with measure zero and guessed not. I'll delete the parenthetical though

Comment: But it doesn't really matter that the first function is discontinuous everywhere. That is more than you need to draw the conclusion. You only need that $f$ is discontinuous at the irrationals, as you said at first. You should state the key fact here, that a function is Riemann integrable iff the set of points where it's discontinuous has measure zero.

Comment: Fair enough. I will edit